# Bazel not adding BUILD file to external dependency

Tags: go, bazel

I have a workspace where I use gazelle to generate my BUILD files and for some reason the `com_github_ipfs_go_merkledag` dependency is breaking the build when trying to resolve it's `github.com/gogo/protobuf/gogoproto` dependency. The setup and run is below.

Workspace:

```
# Declare indirect dependencies and init toolchains.
go_rules_dependencies()

go_register_toolchains(version = "1.16")

go_embed_data_dependencies()

load("@rules_proto//proto:repositories.bzl", "rules_proto_dependencies", "rules_proto_toolchains")

rules_proto_dependencies()

rules_proto_toolchains()

load("@bazel_gazelle//:deps.bzl", "gazelle_dependencies", "go_repository")

gazelle_dependencies()
```

Commands:

```
bazel run //:gazelle
bazel run //:gazelle -- update-repos -from_file=go.mod
bazel build //...
```

Output:

```
...
no such package '@com_github_ipfs_go_merkledag//github.com/gogo/protobuf/gogoproto':
BUILD file not found in directory 'github.com/gogo/protobuf/gogoproto' of external repository @com_github_ipfs_go_merkledag. 
Add a BUILD file to a directory to mark it as a package. and referenced by '@com_github_ipfs_go_merkledag//pb:merkledag_pb_go_proto'
...
```

Not sure what the solution for this is?

Answer (score 2):

Add build directives to the go_repository to ignore

```
go_repository(
    name = "com_github_ipfs_go_merkledag",
    importpath = "github.com/ipfs/go-merkledag",
    sum = "h1:ixNu/5MJSaT/Qs073T0/HsWKwnOoBgqSq1g+GaJIen0=",
    version = "v0.4.0",
    build_directives = [
        "gazelle:proto disable",
    ],
)
```